# Required field validator not responding or firing

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have several text boxes on my website, each with a required field validator, and a submit button on the bottom. The submit button works whether or not I have entered values into the text boxes. Below is the code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxName"  ValidationGroup="textgroup" runat="server" 
     ToolTip="Insert the Pokemon's name" CssClass="upper-case" />       
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"  
    ValidationGroup="textgroup" Text="Names only please" ControlToValidate="TextBoxName" 
    ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]*$" CssClass="required-field" />
<br />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" ValidationGroup="textgroup" 
  runat="server" Text="Required Field" ControlToValidate="TextBoxName" 
  CssClass="required-field" />
<br />
```

Here is the submit button:

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Insert Card" ValidationGroup="textgroup" />
```

And the code-behind for the submit button:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Page.Validate()
        CardCollectionDataSource.Insert()
```

Comment: Tested your snippet. It works as it should, which means you have a JavaScript error somewhere on your page. Check the console.

Comment: Can you try to replace Page.Validate with if(Page.IsValid)?